# Proper way crossplatfom convert from std::string to 'const TCHAR *'

Tags: c++, cross-platform, multiplatform

I'm working for crossplatrofm project in c++ and I have variable with type `std::string` and need convert it to `const TCHAR *` - what is proper way, may be functions from some library ?

**UPD 1**: - as I see in function definition there is split windows and non-Windows implementations:

```
#if defined _MSC_VER || defined __MINGW32__
#define _tinydir_char_t TCHAR
#else
#define _tinydir_char_t char
#endif
```

- so is it a really no way for non spliting realization for send parameter from `std::string` ?

Comment: `TCHAR` and "cross platform" doesn't really make sense, given that `TCHAR` is Windows only.

Comment: Thanks - hmm - you mean that in Linux for example Unicode string will be just a char ?

Comment: @Alexander `wchar_t` is wide char type present in C++. `WCHAR`, present in windows headers, is, typically, defined as `wchar_t`.

Comment: `std::string` is just a container it says nothing about the underlying encoding of the data it contains; for example it might contain ASCII, MBCS or UTF-8.  I suggest you consider rewording your question to something like:  "What standard containers are best suited to the various character encodings (both Unicode and non-unicode) and how do I convert between {insert list of encodings you are interested in}."

Comment: 'as I see in function definition'... Where is that function from? Is that your function? In that case, do not split the declaration.

Comment: @user2079303 - this is from https://github.com/cxong/tinydir - function `tinydir_open` second parameter "path" - as you understand this can be Unicode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TCHAR` are Windows type and it defined in this way:

```
#ifdef  UNICODE                     
typedef wchar_t TCHAR, *PTCHAR;
#else
typedef char TCHAR, *PTCHAR;
#endif
```

`UNICODE` macro is typically defined in project settings (in case when your use Visual Studio project on Windows).

You can get the `const TCHAR*` from `std::string` (which is ASCII or UTF8 in most cases) in this way:

```
std::string s("hello world");
const TCHAR* pstring = nullptr;
#ifdef UNICODE
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    std::wstring wstr = converter.from_bytes(s);
    pstring = wstr.data();
#else
    pstring = s.data();
#endif
```

`pstring` will be the result.

But it's highly not recommended to use the `TCHAR` on other platforms. It's better to use the UTF8 strings (char*) within `std::string`

Comment: *"`std::string` (which is always ASCII string)"* No, it's not always ASCII. It can be any narrow character encoding, but assuming the content is from standard library calls, then it is in the native narrow character encoding of the system. Which is often (but not always) UTF-8 in Linux. I think it is one of Microsoft's code pages in windows, which depends on the OS localization. Most, if not all of these are supersets of ASCII, though.

Comment: @user2079303 thanks for comment. Edited answer according to it.

Comment: Also note that `wstring_convert` and `codecvt_utf8_utf16` (and other facets from `<codecvt>`) are deprecated in C++17) and there is no alternative unicode conversion functionality in the standard library yet.

Answer (score 2):

> Proper way crossplatfom convert from std::string to 'const TCHAR *'

`TCHAR` should not be used in cross platform programs at all; Except of course, when interacting with windows API calls, but those need to be abstracted away from the rest of the program or else it won't be cross-platform. So, you only need to convert between `TCHAR` strings and `char` strings in windows specific code.

The rest of the program should use `char`, and preferably assume that it contains UTF-8 encoded strings. If user input, or system calls return strings that are in a different encoding, you need to figure out what that encoding is, and convert accordingly.

Character encoding conversion functionality of the C++ standard library is rather weak, so that is not of much use. You can implement the conversion according the encoding specification or you can use a third party implementation, as always.

> may be functions from some library ?

I recommend this.

> as I see in function definition there is split windows and non-Windows implementations

The library that you use doesn't provide a uniform API to different platforms, so it cannot be used in a truly cross-platform way. You can write a wrapper library with uniform function declarations that handles the character encoding conversion on platforms that need it.

Or, you can use another library, which provides a uniform API and converts the encoding transparently.

Answer (score 1):

I came across boost.nowide the other day. I think it will do exactly what you want.

http://cppcms.com/files/nowide/html/

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you should not be using TCHAR except in code that interfaces with the Windows API (or libraries modeled after the Windows API).

Another alternative is to use the character conversion classes/macros defined in atlconv.h.  CA2T will convert an 8-bit character string to a TCHAR string.  CA2CT will convert to a const TCHAR string (LPCTSTR).  Assuming your 8-bit strings are UTF-8, you should specify CP_UTF8 as the code page for the conversion.

If you want to declare a variable containing a TCHAR copy of a std::string:

```
CA2T tstr(stdstr.c_str(), CP_UTF8);
```

If you want to call a function that takes an LPCTSTR:

```
FunctionThatTakesString(CA2CT(stdsr.c_str(), CP_UTF8));
```

If you want to construct a std::string from a TCHAR string:

```
std::string mystdstring(CT2CA(tstr, CP_UTF8));
```

If you want to call a function that takes an LPTSTR then maybe you should not be using these conversion classes.  (But you can if you know that the function you are calling does not modify the string outside its current length.)